# 'get_category_parents' function is not working

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to get parent category of particular category.
Using,

```
$slug = $_REQUEST['product_cat'];
$category = get_term_by( 'slug', $slug, 'product_cat' );
$catid = $category->term_id;
    
$categories = get_category_parents( $catid );
print_r($categories);
```

I can get cat id. but can't get parent category using this.
I am using this code in loop-start.php of woo-commerce template.

I am geting following errors.

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/html/printvenue_new/wp-includes/category-template.php on line 53
>
> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/html/printvenue_new/wp-includes/category-template.php on line 55

I want parent category any how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I understand you correctly. AFAIK, woocommerce uses custom taxonomies, not the build in taxonomy `category`. For this reason, your code will not work.

There is now function like `get_category_parents()` for custom taxonomies. You need to create your own custom function, something like @ialocin has described [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/113825/31545)

On a taxonomy page, you can get the current queried object ( the term being viewed ) with `get_queried_object()`. From here you can get the parent ID

```
    $parent_id = get_queried_object()->parent;
```

If `$parent_id` is `0`, it means it is the highest most top level term. Any other value means that it has a parent. Then you can simply get that parent with `get_term_by()` using the parent ID and so on.

Hope it helps

Comment: My pleasure. Enjoy :-)

Comment: well, with which short key i can do stuff like you are doing with error in my question ???

Comment: Just add a `>` sign in the beginning of the paragragh, this will add your error code in a blockquote. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one for get parent category :

```
<?php echo get_category_parents( $catid , true, ' &raquo; ' ); ?>
```

you want add two or more parameter on this.

Comment: Try this one.

`$cat_id=7;//current category's ID (e.g. 7)
$separator='&raquo;';//The separator to use
$category = get_category($cat_id);//$category is the current category object
$parent_id = $category[0]->category_parent //category's parent ID
$ancestors = get_category_parents($parent_id, true, $separator);`

Comment: Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/html/printvenue_new/wp-content/themes/printvenue/woocommerce/loop/loop-start.php on line 40

Comment: 40 mi line ma aa code 6 
$parent_id = $category[0]->category_parent;

Comment: under line 40 put this and check what is come on there.

echo $category[0]->category_parent;

OR

var_dump($category);
and check it out .